# How to create an Enum object in Python C API?

Tags: python, c, python-c-api

I'm struggling how to create a python Enum object inside the Python C API. The enum class has assigned `tp_base` to `PyEnum_Type`, so it inherits Enum. But, I can't figure out a way to tell the Enum base class what items are in the enum. I want to allow iteration and lookup from Python using the `__members__` attribute that every Python Enum provides.

Thank you,

Jelle

Comment: Are you trying to create an `Enum` *instance* or a new `Enum` *type*?

Comment: I'm trying to declare an Enum type such as "Season" or "Month". If I understand it correctly, each item in an Enum represents a static instance of that Enum, right?

Comment: The enum is *not* created in C, it is created **in Python**, and this is an important distinction.

Comment: Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68490194/208880) help?

Comment: Personally I'd probably do it using `PyRun_SimpleString` or similar - we do have access to the Python interpreter from the C API so why not use it for things like this. I'm reluctant to post it as an answer though (because it's clearly isn't "the spirit of the question")

Comment: @DavidW: Please do post it, it would still be useful to those of us with minimal C experience.

Answer (score 4):

It is not straightforward at all. The `Enum` is a *Python class* using a *Python metaclass*. It is possible to create it in C but it will be just *emulating* the constructing Python code in C - the end result is the same and while it speeds up things slightly, you'll most probably run the code only once within each program run.

In any case it *is* possible, but it is not easy at all. I'll show how to do it in Python:

```py
from enum import Enum

class Color(Enum):
    RED = 1
    GREEN = 2
    BLUE = 3

print(Color)
print(Color.RED)
```

is the same as:

```py
from enum import Enum

name = 'Color'
bases = (Enum,)
enum_meta = type(Enum)

namespace = enum_meta.__prepare__(name, bases)
namespace['RED'] = 1
namespace['GREEN'] = 2
namespace['BLUE'] = 3

Color = enum_meta(name, bases, namespace)

print(Color)
print(Color.RED)
```

The latter is the code that you need to translate into C.

Answer (score 3):

*Edited note:* [An answer on a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69281896/4657412) details how `enum.Enum` has a functional interface that can be used instead.  That is almost certainly the correct approach. I think my answer here is a useful alternative approach to be aware of, although it probably isn't the best solution to this problem.

---

I'm aware that this answer is slightly cheating, but this is exactly the kind of code that's better written in Python, and in the C API we still have access to the full Python interpreter. My reasoning for this is that the main reason to keep things entirely in C is performance, and it seems unlikely that creating enum objects will be performance critical.

I'll give three versions, essentially depending on the level of complexity.

---

First, the simplest case: the enum is entirely known and defined and compile-time. Here we simply set up an empty global dict, run the Python code, then extract the enum from the global dict:

```c
PyObject* get_enum(void) {
    const char str[] = "from enum import Enum\n"
                       "class Colour(Enum):\n"
                       "    RED = 1\n"
                       "    GREEN = 2\n"
                       "    BLUE = 3\n"
                       "";
    PyObject *global_dict=NULL, *should_be_none=NULL, *output=NULL;
    global_dict = PyDict_New();
    if (!global_dict) goto cleanup;
    should_be_none = PyRun_String(str, Py_file_input, global_dict, global_dict);
    if (!should_be_none) goto cleanup;
    // extract Color from global_dict
    output = PyDict_GetItemString(global_dict, "Colour");
    if (!output) {
        // PyDict_GetItemString does not set exceptions
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "could not get 'Colour'");
    } else {
        Py_INCREF(output); // PyDict_GetItemString returns a borrow reference
    }
    cleanup:
    Py_XDECREF(global_dict);
    Py_XDECREF(should_be_none);
    return output;
}
```

---

Second, we might want to change what we define in C at runtime. For example, maybe the input parameters pick the enum values. Here, I'm going to use string formatting to insert the appropriate values into our string. There's a number of options here: `sprintf`, `PyBytes_Format`, the C++ standard library, using Python strings (perhaps with another call into Python code?). Pick whichever you're most comfortable with.

```c
PyObject* get_enum_fmt(int red, int green, int blue) {
    const char str[] = "from enum import Enum\n"
                       "class Colour(Enum):\n"
                       "    RED = %d\n"
                       "    GREEN = %d\n"
                       "    BLUE = %d\n"
                       "";
    PyObject *formatted_str=NULL, *global_dict=NULL, *should_be_none=NULL, *output=NULL;

    formatted_str = PyBytes_FromFormat(str, red, green, blue);
    if (!formatted_str) goto cleanup;
    global_dict = PyDict_New();
    if (!global_dict) goto cleanup;
    should_be_none = PyRun_String(PyBytes_AsString(formatted_str), Py_file_input, global_dict, global_dict);
    if (!should_be_none) goto cleanup;
    // extract Color from global_dict
    output = PyDict_GetItemString(global_dict, "Colour");
    if (!output) {
        // PyDict_GetItemString does not set exceptions
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "could not get 'Colour'");
    } else {
        Py_INCREF(output); // PyDict_GetItemString returns a borrow reference
    }
    cleanup:
    Py_XDECREF(formatted_str);
    Py_XDECREF(global_dict);
    Py_XDECREF(should_be_none);
    return output;
}
```

Obviously you can do as much or as little as you like with string formatting - I've just picked a simple example to show the point. The main differences from the previous version are the call to `PyBytes_FromFormat` to set up the string, and the call to `PyBytes_AsString` that gets the underlying `char*` out of the prepared `bytes` object.

---

Finally, we could prepare the enum attributes in C Python `dict` and pass it in. This necessitates a bit of a change. Essentially I use @AnttiHaapala's lower-level Python code, but insert `namespace.update(contents)` after the call to `__prepare__`.

```c
PyObject* get_enum_dict(const char* key1, int value1, const char* key2, int value2) {
    const char str[] = "from enum import Enum\n"
                       "name = 'Colour'\n"
                       "bases = (Enum,)\n"
                       "enum_meta = type(Enum)\n"
                       "namespace = enum_meta.__prepare__(name, bases)\n"
                       "namespace.update(contents)\n"
                       "Colour = enum_meta(name, bases, namespace)\n";

    PyObject *global_dict=NULL, *contents_dict=NULL, *value_as_object=NULL, *should_be_none=NULL, *output=NULL;
    global_dict = PyDict_New();
    if (!global_dict) goto cleanup;

    // create and fill the contents dictionary
    contents_dict = PyDict_New();
    if (!contents_dict) goto cleanup;
    value_as_object = PyLong_FromLong(value1);
    if (!value_as_object) goto cleanup;
    int set_item_result = PyDict_SetItemString(contents_dict, key1, value_as_object);
    Py_CLEAR(value_as_object);
    if (set_item_result!=0) goto cleanup;
    value_as_object = PyLong_FromLong(value2);
    if (!value_as_object) goto cleanup;
    set_item_result = PyDict_SetItemString(contents_dict, key2, value_as_object);
    Py_CLEAR(value_as_object);
    if (set_item_result!=0) goto cleanup;

    set_item_result = PyDict_SetItemString(global_dict, "contents", contents_dict);
    if (set_item_result!=0) goto cleanup;

    should_be_none = PyRun_String(str, Py_file_input, global_dict, global_dict);
    if (!should_be_none) goto cleanup;
    // extract Color from global_dict
    output = PyDict_GetItemString(global_dict, "Colour");
    if (!output) {
        // PyDict_GetItemString does not set exceptions
        PyErr_SetString(PyExc_KeyError, "could not get 'Colour'");
    } else {
        Py_INCREF(output); // PyDict_GetItemString returns a borrow reference
    }
    cleanup:
    Py_XDECREF(contents_dict);
    Py_XDECREF(global_dict);
    Py_XDECREF(should_be_none);
    return output;
}
```

Again, this presents a reasonably flexible way to get values from C into a generated enum.

---

For the sake of testing I used the follow simple Cython wrapper - this is just presented for completeness to help people try these functions.

```
cdef extern from "cenum.c":
    object get_enum()
    object get_enum_fmt(int, int, int)
    object get_enum_dict(char*, int, char*, int)


def py_get_enum():
    return get_enum()

def py_get_enum_fmt(red, green, blue):
    return get_enum_fmt(red, green, blue)

def py_get_enum_dict(key1, value1, key2, value2):
    return get_enum_dict(key1, value1, key2, value2)
```

---

To reiterate: this answer is only partly in the C API, but the approach of calling Python from C is one that I've found productive at times for "run-once" code that would be tricky to write entirely in C.

Comment: Thanks ;D I was considering whether I should try to code this in C myself but fortunately I need not consider that any more